# difference between options and originalOptions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between options and originalOptions in [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) ? I read the docs but I am still confused about the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

options are the request options, while originalOptions are the original options you passed in to $.ajax.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {

    // here options will have all the request information
    {url : 'test.html', 
     type: "GET", 
     isLocal: false, 
     global: true, 
     processData: true,
     hasContent: false,
     jsonp: "callback",
     jsonpCallback: function () { ... },
     responseFields: ......
      …  and a lot more

    // while originalOptions will be exactly the same as the object passed
    // to $.ajax below 
    {url : 'test.html', dataType: 'html'}
});

$.ajax({
    url : 'test.html',
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Comment: This is basically what the jQuery documentation says. If he didn't understand it there, I don't think this will help him much.

Comment: Perhaps add an example showing how it's used, and what the values of the two parameters would be.

Comment: Srs bro? I linked the docs, you just said the exact same thing in the docs.

Comment: @0xSina - That's because the DOCS explains it pretty darn good.